# Run pyspark in the Python environment created by anaconda on the spark installed in k8s

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda, kubernetes-helm

I configured the Spark node using helm in k8s, but there was a problem when I called Spark using pySpark in the Conda environment. However, I used Spark-submit and there was no problem

Firstly, I configured the spark nodes on K8S using helm.

Configure bitnami/park using values. yaml as follows

```
global:
  storageClass: nfs-client-storageclass //nfs
service:
  type: NodePort
```

When I build spark submit, the spark program runs perfectly. But when I ran pyspark on anaconda, the program encountered an error.

I have tried many methods to set nodeport, set environment variables, change the PySpark version to be consistent with Spark, and configure Spark. driver. host. It is worth mentioning that when I configure Spark. driver. host. exec will not report an error, but there is a communication issue between exec and driver, and I currently do not know how to adjust it.

The error is as follows

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Pyspark is as follows

```
import os
import random
import traceback
import warnings

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/opt/spark"
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/opt/miniconda3/envs/Python/bin/python3.10"
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkPi")
    .master("k8s://https://192.168.100.150:6443")
    .config("spark.driver.host", "192.168.100.150")
    .config("spark.network.timeout", "300")
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "3")
    .config("spark.driver.cores", "1")
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "1024m")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "1024m")
    .config("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "spark")
    .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy", "IfNotPresent")
    .config(
        "spark.kubernetes.container.image",
        "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/cm_ns01/apache-spark:v3.2.3",
    )
    .config(
        "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "my-release-spark"
    )
    .config(
        "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName", "my-release-spark"
    )
    .config(
        "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true"
    )
    .config(
        "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true"
    )
    .getOrCreate()
)

pi = (
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 3001), 3000)
    .map(lambda x: (x - 0.5) / 3000)
    .map(lambda x: 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x))
    .reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
)

print("Pi is roughly %f" % pi)
spark.stop()
```